# Amazon Marketplace Webservices - Inventory sample feed

Tags: amazon-mws, amazonsellercentral

do you have any links to Amazon Marketplace Webservices sample XML Inventory feeds or Flat files but not XSD schemes as they are messy?

cheers,
/Marcin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you are looking for the [Text-File Templates](https://sellercentral.amazon.com/gp/help/help.html/ref=ag_1641_cont_13461?ie=UTF8&itemID=1641&language=en_US) section of Seller Central Help. On this page there is a listing of different types of inventory feed templates that you can use to learn the different fields and their definitions etc.

Comment: please note you must have an amazon seller's account to gain access to those templates.

Answer (score 7):

Download php library api folder of any Amazon API from

https://developer.amazonservices.co.uk/

and you fill find samples folder under src\MarketplaceWebService\Samples

Under this Samples Folder there are many sample php files that you can test and in this sample files you will find XML feed which we needs to submit to amazon api.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
<Header>
<DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
<MerchantIdentifier>$merchant_token</MerchantIdentifier>
</Header>
<MessageType>Inventory</MessageType>
<Message>
<MessageID>1</MessageID>
<OperationType>Update</OperationType>
<Inventory>
<SKU>$sku</SKU>
<Quantity>$quantity</Quantity>
<FulfillmentLatency>1</FulfillmentLatency>
</Inventory>
</Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

LIST of all Feed Types for different operations:

> _POST_PRODUCT_DATA_ for Product Feed Type XML
>   _POST_PRODUCT_RELATIONSHIP_DATA_  for Item Relationship Feed Type XML
>   _POST_ITEM_DATA_  for Item Feeds Type XML
>   _POST_OFFER_ONLY_DATA_  for Offer Only Feeds Type XML
>   _POST_WEBSTORE_ITEM_DATA_  for WebStore Item Feeds Type XML
>   _POST_PRODUCT_IMAGE_DATA_  for Image Feeds Type XML  _POST_PRODUCT_PRICING_DATA_  for Price Feeds Type XML 
>   _POST_INVENTORY_AVAILABILITY_DATA_  for Inventory Feeds Type XML  _POST_ORDER_FULFILLMENT_DATA_  for Shipment confirmation Type XML  _POST_FULFILLMENT_ORDER_CANCELLATION_REQUEST_DATA_ for Fulfillment Order Cancellation Request Type XML
>   _POST_PRODUCT_OVERRIDES_DATA_ 
>   for Product Shipping Override Feeds Type XML 
>   _POST_SHIPPING_OVERRIDE_DATA_  for Shipping Override Feeds Type XML